# rust, polars, polars Decimal type in scheme converts to f64

Tags: rust, dtype

I have csv file with format

```
2008-03-19 10:15:00,69.00,56.37,59.50,59.50,34803018,34793218,
2008-03-19 10:16:00,64.00,58.05,59.50,59.50,38839940,4024922,
```

I want to read this file with dtypes `Datetime, Decimal, Decimal, Decimal, Decimal, UInt64, UInt64`

This code works:

```
    let mut scheme = pl::Schema::new();
    scheme
        .insert_at_index(
            0,
            "timestamp".into(),
            pl::DataType::Datetime(pl::TimeUnit::Milliseconds, None),
        )
        .unwrap();
    scheme
        .insert_at_index(1, "open".into(), pl::DataType::Decimal(Some(12), Some(4)))
        .unwrap();
    scheme
        .insert_at_index(2, "high".into(), pl::DataType::Decimal(Some(12), Some(4)))
        .unwrap();
    scheme
        .insert_at_index(3, "low".into(), pl::DataType::Decimal(Some(12), Some(4)))
        .unwrap();
    scheme
        .insert_at_index(4, "close".into(), pl::DataType::Decimal(Some(12), Some(4)))
        .unwrap();
    scheme
        .insert_at_index(5, "volume".into(), pl::DataType::UInt32)
        .unwrap();
    scheme
        .insert_at_index(6, "open_interest".into(), pl::DataType::UInt32)
        .unwrap();

    let visa = pl::CsvReader::from_path("src/data/V.csv")
        .expect("expected path to the csv file")
        .with_separator(b',')
        .truncate_ragged_lines(true)
        .with_n_threads(Some(2))
        .with_dtypes(Some(Arc::new(scheme)))
        .with_skip_rows(1_600_000)
        .finish();
```

And I have result dtypes:

```
│ datetime[ms] ┆ decimal[12,4] ┆ decimal[12,4] ┆ decimal[12,4] ┆ decimal[12,4] ┆ u64 ┆ u64│
```

But I thought this is unconvinient and tried different approach:

```
    let f1 = pl::Field::new(
        "timestamp",
        pl::DataType::Datetime(pl::TimeUnit::Milliseconds, None),
    );
    let f2 = pl::Field::new("open", pl::DataType::Decimal(Some(12), Some(4)));
    println!("{}", f2.data_type()); // ===> decimal[12,4]
    let f3 = pl::Field::new("high", pl::DataType::Decimal(Some(12), Some(4)));
    let f4 = pl::Field::new("low", pl::DataType::Decimal(Some(12), Some(4)));
    let f5 = pl::Field::new("close", pl::DataType::Decimal(Some(12), Some(4)));
    let f6 = pl::Field::new("volume", pl::DataType::UInt64);
    let f7 = pl::Field::new("open_interest", pl::DataType::UInt64);
    let sc = pl::Schema::from_iter(vec![f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6, f7]);
    println!("{}", sc.get("open").unwrap()); // ===> f64????????? Why ????
    let visa = pl::CsvReader::from_path("src/data/V.csv")
        .expect("expected path to the csv file")
        .with_separator(b',')
        .truncate_ragged_lines(true)
        .with_dtypes(Some(Arc::new(sc)))
        .with_skip_rows(1_600_000)
        .with_n_threads(Some(2))
        .finish();

    println!("{:?}", visa.unwrap());
```

That's seems much better, but gives me incorrect dtypes for some reason...

```
│ datetime[ms] ┆ f64 ┆ f64 ┆ f64 ┆ f64 ┆ u64 ┆ u64 │
```

Is it bug or I didn't get something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because polars [converts `Decimal` to `Float64` in `Schema::from_iter`](https://docs.rs/polars-core/0.35.4/src/polars_core/schema.rs.html#55-67) if [`$POLARS_ACTIVATE_DECIMAL` is not set to "1"](https://docs.rs/polars-core/0.35.4/src/polars_core/config.rs.html#33-39)

> ```rust
>            #[cfg(feature = "dtype-decimal")]
>            let fld = match fld.dtype {
>                DataType::Decimal(_, _) => {
>                    if crate::config::decimal_is_active() {
>                        fld
>                    } else {
>                        let mut fld = fld.clone();
>                        fld.coerce(DataType::Float64);
>                        fld
>                    }
>                },
>                _ => fld,
>            };
> ```

You can either run with an apropriate environment, for example with something like `POLARS_ACTIVATE_DECIMAL=1 your_executable` or set that environment variable from your code<sup>1</sup> to preserve the datatype:

```rust
use polars::prelude::*;
fn main() {
    std::env::set_var("POLARS_ACTIVATE_DECIMAL", "1");

    let open = Field::new("open", DataType::Decimal(Some(1), Some(1)));
    let sc = Schema::from_iter(vec![open]);
    dbg!(sc.get_field("open"));
}
```

outputs

```
sc.get_field("open") = Some(
    Field {
        name: "open",
        dtype: Decimal(
            Some(
                1,
            ),
            Some(
                1,
            ),
        ),
    },
)
```

as expected.

---

<sup>1: It's likely surprising for the user and thus discouraged to ignore the environment that way though</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much! Very informative answer!